# Trying to select a entire range under a row label in a pivot table

Tags: vba, select, excel, range, pivot-table

I am trying to select all the rows under a specific row label but with my code I am only able to select the first Row under each row label.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, here is my code.

```
 Sub ttest()
 Dim pt As PivotTable
 Set pt = Sheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

 pt.PivotFields("Pillar").PivotItems("CL").DataRange.EntireRow.Select

 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to select the rows? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to select the rows because all the info in the rows will be exported to a report.

Comment: This is because the current format understand that the data doesn't lie with the PivotItem, but to the subitems. I did a trick. I changed the Pivot Table layout to Tabular Format, by going to Design--> Report Layout --> Show in Tabular Form

And then this code worked:

    Dim pTable As PivotTable
    Dim pField As PivotField
    Dim pField2 As PivotField
    
    Set pTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    
    Dim pItem As PivotItem
    
    
    Set pField = pTable.PivotFields(1)
    Set pItem = pField.PivotItems(1)
    pItem.DataRange.Offset(0, -1).EntireRow.Select

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to copy the rows. Should work on your existing set of code:

```
PT.PivotSelect "'CL' Rows[All]", xlDataAndLabel + xlFirstRow, True
```

Copied through Macro Recorder.

Edit: You can always use offset to edit the current selection. I mean to increase or decrease number of selected rows.

Thanks,
V

Comment: For me it only worked using just "CL" (Rows[All] triggered an error).